# Post Photos as Fan Page not as User (Post as User Working 100%)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I´m trying to post Photos on my Fan Page using Facebook API but the Posts appears as my User and not as Fan Page it self.

I know i should use the Page Access Token instead of the App User Access Token but when i put the Page Access Token i get:

**Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource.**

What should i do to post the Image as Fan Page itself not as the app Owner ?

Here´s the Working Code:

```
require_once('src/facebook.php');

$pageid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    "appId"  => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "secret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "cookie" => true,
));

$args = array(
    'access_token' => $accessToken,
    "url"      => "http://example.com/image.jpg",
    "message"  => "Picture Caption",
    );    

$facebook->api("/$pageid/photos?access_token='.$accessToken","post",$args);
```

Comment: so you are using hardcoded access token?

Comment: Hello @Darvex, actually i was using User Access Token and when i tried to use Page Access Token provided by Open Graph i got the error above. I just figure it out how to fix this. I´ll answer my own question if anyone else have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out what was wrong. I was using wrong Page Access Token, the right way to get the **right** Page Access Token is through the following link:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

You can even try the new Access Token on Debug Tools:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

If you do that you´ll see a field named "Profile ID", this field has to be the same as your Fan Page ID, and probably will.

Now all my post appear as my Fan Page.

Hope someone else find this usefull.